# Simple explanation of MySql code

Tags: mysql

I am creating a project where I join three tables. In order to complete it I will need to explain each individual line and how they work.

```
SELECT competition.*, teams.team_name, teams.team_position      
FROM competition         
INNER JOIN players     
ON teams.team_id = competition.team_id        
INNER JOIN sports 
ON sports.sport_id = competition.sport_id             
WHERE team_level = 'Professional';
```

I have a basic understanding of the inner joins, however I would appreciate greater explanation.

Many Thanks

Comment: This isnt on-topic for this [**forum**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You should read a tutorial like this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT competition.*, teams.team_name, teams.team_position
```

In this line you are selecting whole competition table and form teams table you are selecting `team_name` and `team_position`.

```
INNER JOIN players
```

The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects all rows from both tables players and competition.

```
ON teams.team_id = competition.team_id
```

gives the criteria on the basis you are selecting.

```
WHERE team_level = 'Professional';
```

The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion means column have value Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join is, to bring rows which satisfy some constraint.

For example:

```
INNER JOIN  sports ON sports.sport_id = competition_sport_id
```

Means, you bring the rows of sports and competition table together, which satisfy `sport_id = competition_sport_id`

Where statement filters out which doesn't satisfy a constraint.

For example:

```
WHERE team_level = 'Professional'
```

Means that you get the rows with column `team_level` with entry `Professional`, and filter out the rest.